# Fill automatically login information on "Connect to server" dialog of SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

**Background** : I made a script in Inno setup to install SQL server, SSMS and so on. And i want all installtion are automatic until connection inormation in Connect to server dialog of SSMS.

I'd like at the first connection with SSMS the connection information, in Connect to Server dialog, are already filled with good information, with a script or other (NOT WITH SSMS) (cf Red rectangle in image)[SSMS connection prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN1Ra.png). Because normally at first start all red retangles are empty and I want to fill them at the end of my installer script.

I find the UserSettings.xml file in ./User//AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0, but I want to know if there is another way, by script or other, without just copy the UserSettings.xml file ?

Thanks

Comment: Removed `inno-setup` tag, as this question is really asking about SQL Server. (This question may be more appropriate for the dba site.)